# How to create multiple html/text files at the same time using CMD/Powershell

Tags: html, powershell, cmd, static

Can I ask if anyone knows how to create multiple html files using CMD or Powershell (preferably CMD)?

I have here a long list of book titles and I'd like to create a static page for each.

**Here's what I'm hoping to achieve:**

To turn this list

```
thecharacterdesign
stealthisbook
seo2020
giveandtake
originals
accounting101
americangovernment101
anatomy101
architecture101
art101
astrology101
astronomy101
buddhism101
...
```

into these (inside a folder this time):

```
thecharacterdesign.html
stealthisbook.html
seo2020.html
giveandtake.html
originals.html
accounting101.html
americangovernment101.html
anatomy101.html
architecture101.html
art101.html
astrology101.html
astronomy101.html
buddhism101.html
...
```

I am not good with CMD or Powershell, but I believe this is doable?

I used to create batch folders before using CMD, but I'm not sure how to tweak the command below to create a text/html instead:

```
md thecharacterdesign stealthisbook seo2020 giveandtake originals accounting101
```

If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks

EDIT: I need a to create lots of blank html files inside a single folder with the names given above and more.

Comment: Do you just want to create a number of blank files with the .html file extension in the folder, or do you actually want to create actual HTML files with some basic content from your list?

Comment: Did you want to create folders from text list and in each folder create a HTML file inside with the same name ? is this what you want ?

Comment: TL;DR: Blank html inside a single folder is enough.
Hi, blank html files will be good enough for me and I'll fill the content one at a time once the files are created. Thank you for responding to my question.

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %%a in (list.txt) do ( MD "%%a" & break>"%%a\%%a.html" )`

Comment: Hi @Stephan, I tried that but it won't work for me. I just copied the whole command, I'm not sure how to use it :(

Comment: `%%a` is batch file syntax. To use it directly on the command line, use `%a` only (each occurrence)

Comment: I tried it again and now it created folders instead of html files? I typed ```for /f "delims=" %a in (list.txt) do ( MD "%a" & break>"%a\%a.html" )``` and sourcing a list.txt for the names

Comment: ... and html files inside each folder. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Hi mygood! I didn't notice there's an html file inside. This is almost good, just that, I'd like to have them all in a single folder only.

Comment: Why did you use `md` (**m**ake**d**irecotry) in the first place? Skip the `md` command and do just `... do break>"%a.html"` or `... do break>"wanted Folder\%a.html"`

Comment: Thank you so much! It's all good now. One problem though is I have about 5301 total file names on the list, but the created files is around 5254. This is easy to fix though, I'll just manually locate and create those missing files. You helped me save lots of time. Hope I can give your answer a check.

Comment: You may want to ask another question for this issue, showing some of the missing entries (maybe there are some special chars in there, which may be easy to fix)

Comment: I'd check on that! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an empty file for each entry of a text file, use a `for /f` loop. (See `for /?` for more information)

```
for /f "delims=" %a in (list.txt) do break>"%a.html"
```

If you want them to be in a certain folder (has to exist):

```
for /f "delims=" %a in (list.txt) do break>"C:\desired folder\%a.html"
```

Note: this is command-line syntax. To use the command within a batch file, use `%%a` instead of `%a` (both occurrences)

Answer (score 1):

Simple way of doing what you want in Powershell:

```
# $titles = @('book','book2')
$titles = Get-Content .\BookTitles.txt

foreach ($title in $titles) {
    $fileName = $title + '.html'
    New-Item -ItemType file -Name $fileName -WhatIf
}
```

I've commented out the first part of the code snippet (the line starting with #) and added a new line using the Get-Content in stead.

What `Get-Content` does is grab each line of the text file BookTitles.txt and add it as a separate entry in the $titles array.

Right now there's a `-WhatIf` at the end of the line creating the actual files. You can run the code as it is presented and it will tell you what it is going to do. When you feel confident it does what you want, remove `-WhatIf` and running the code will create the files for you.

Comment: Hi can you please expand on how to use the ```Get-Content```? Will it be easier to use? If I understand it correctly, it will create multiple files and getting the names for each on a sourced text file? Cause I have here about 5000 titles that I need to turn into an html file, and this method will be very difficult.

Comment: Thank you so much @Laage! I already got the answer from @Stephan. But I'll keep this important code to be used in the future. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

In a batch file you can try like this :

```
@echo off
Set "List=%~dp0List.txt"
Set "MyFolder=%~dp0MyFolder"
If Not Exist "%MyFolder%" MD "%MyFolder%"
@for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%List%"') do (
    echo. 2>"%MyFolder%\%%a.html"
)
pause
```